# Avoid crashing VBA when running IE web scraping multiple times

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, crash, screen-scraping

My excel crashes when I scrape a website for information multiple times, and insert it into cell

I already included in my code set IE = Nothing and IE Quit, but it doesn't change the fact that the code returns an error after multiple iterations

My code consists of a loop-part and the actual scraping. Here is the loop:

```
Public Sub LooperForMMDescription()
Dim currentValue As String
Dim dataList As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim IE As Object
    n = 1
    Set dataList = Range("Table6")
    FirstRow = Range("Table6").Row - 1
    'On Error Resume Next
    Set IE = Nothing

    For i = 1 To UBound(dataList.Value)
        If IsEmpty(dataList.Value) Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            currentValue = dataList(i, 1).Text
            If Len(currentValue) = 0 Then
            GoTo ByPass
            End If
            Call MM_description(currentValue, n, FirstRow, IE)
ByPass:
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Sheets("Input").Range("F7").Select
End Sub
```

And this is the actual scraping:

```
Public Sub MM_description(currentValue As String, n As Integer, FirstRow As Integer, IE As Object)

Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim codeLine As String
Dim startPos As Long
Dim endPost As Long

Set IE = Nothing
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False

IE.Navigate2 (currentValue)
Do While IE.Busy
   Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

mes = IE.document.body.innerHTML
startPos = InStr(mes, "Description") + 61
endPos = InStr(mes, "Address")

If startPos = 0 Then
    Sheets("Input").Range("F" & FirstRow + n).Value = "Not Found"
Else
    codeLine = Mid(mes, startPos, endPos - startPos - 229)
    Sheets("Input").Range("F" & FirstRow + n).Value = codeLine

End If
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code runs fine for 80-90 iterations, but then it returns an error

Comment: and what is that error and on which line does it occur? Is the url public? There are a few things to fix in the above.

Comment: Also, what does table6 look like please?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is more of a code review than an answer. The following are notes on your code and a suggested re-write.

---

Use `Long` not `Integer` as this reduces the risk of overflow which can happen with `Integer` datatype particularly when dealing with loops of rows (there are more rows than `Integer` can handle). Additionally, there is no performance benefit here from `Integer v Long`.

---

Camelcase local variables

```
firstRow
```

---

Improve readability by using worksheet variables

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

---

Use explicit sheet references not bug prone implicit `Activesheet` references. Using `ws` variable from above:

```
Range("Table6")
```

which has implicit `Activesheet` reference can have an explicit sheet reference

```
ws.Range("Table6")
```

---

`dataList.value` is a 2d array, as you are reading in a range from a worksheet:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(dataList.Value)
```

So, there should be a second dimension specified in your loop and it would be more efficient to read that 2d array into a variable, rather than incurring the repeated expensive i/o of going out to sheet for a value

I don't know what your `table6` looks like but I suspect you are attempting to loop a specific column (likely the first)

You could then, instead, put the table into a variable and then read its first column values (excluding header) into a 1D array to loop. As you will later be writing out values to the sheet again, dimension an output array to the same dimensions as the array you are looping to store the results of your loop in

```
Dim arr(), table As ListObject, output()

Set table = ws.ListObjects("Table6")
arr = Application.Transpose(table.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value)

ReDim output(1 To UBound(arr))
```

---

This

```
If IsEmpty(dataList.Value) Then
    Exit Sub
Else
```

is basically looking at whether the table databodyrange is empty. Assuming your are checking if there are any urls in column 1 of your table then this test is only needed
once before the loop and can be a one liner without the `If Else End If`

```
If IsEmpty(arr) Then Exit Sub
```

---

Consider renaming local variables to more useful/descriptive values:  `currentValue` to `currentUrl` as this is more useful IMO.

---

This

```
If Len(currentValue) = 0 Then
    GoTo ByPass
End If
```

is basically checking whether there is a value to pass as an url and using GoTo to handle not present. Avoid GoTo where possible as it makes code harder to read. It isn't needed here. You can use a quick `vbNullString` comparison, or even better `Instr(url, "http") > 0` to validate the value you will be working with:

(I have switched from currentValue)

```
'initial code

If currentUrl <> vbNullString Then  'test
    'call the sub and extract value
End If

n = n + 1 'increment....loop....rinse....repeat
```

Alterative validation:

```
If instr(currentUrl, "http") > 0 Then   'test
    'call the sub and extract value
End If

n = n + 1 'increment....loop....rinse....repeat
```

As you already have a loop variable of `i` then `n` isn't really needed at all. Particularly in light of populating an output array at same indices.

---

`ie` is already nothing when you have `Dim ie As`..... You want to instantiate the object at the start

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Then work with that instance throughout your loop. You already include `ie` in your scraping sub signature, so it is expected that you will pass the same instance around:

```
Public Sub MM_description(currentValue As String, n As Long, firstRow As Long, ie As Object)
```

Add `ByRef`, `ByVal` to signature

```
Public Sub MM_description(ByVal currentValue As String, ByVal n As Long, ByVal firstRow As Long, ByVal ie As Object)
```

---

Remove redundant `Call` keyword when calling the sub and remove the `()` as this is a sub with params

```
Call MM_description(currentValue, n, firstRow, ie)  >  MM_description currentValue, n, firstRow, ie
```

As you are passing `ie` to the sub `MM_description` you don't want to then deference it and instantiate a new instance inside the called sub. So, remove

```
Set ie = Nothing
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
```

from inside `MM_description`

Inside the called sub:

Remove the `()` from

```
ie.Navigate2 (currentUrl)
```

So

```
ie.Navigate2 currentUrl
```

and use a proper page load wait. So replace:

```
Do While ie.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

with

```
while .busy or .readystate <> 4:wend
```

---

Remove unused variables e.g. `Dim html As HTMLDocument`, and declare all others that are used e.g. `Dim mes As String`. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to check for consistency of variable spellings and declarations.

---

Now, I would actually convert this sub, `MM_description`, into a function that returns the scraped string value, or `"Not Found"`, and populates the output array in the same loop which calls the function.

If this is now a function the signature needs a return type specified, the call to the function needs an assignment and the `()` come back as there is evaluation.

```
output(i) = MM_description(currentUrl, n, firstRow, ie)
```

---

Finally, write out the `output` array to whichever range you want the output values in one go.

```
Worksheets("Input").Range("F1").Resize(UBound(output), 1) = Application.Transpose(output)
```

---

Many of the above changes would lead to a structure like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LooperForMMDescription()

    Dim currentUrl As String, i As Long
    Dim ie As Object, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set table = ws.ListObjects("Table6")

    Dim arr(), table As ListObject, output()

    arr = Application.Transpose(table.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value)

    ReDim output(1 To UBound(arr))

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    If IsEmpty(arr) Then Exit Sub

    ie.Visible = True

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        currentUrl = arr(i)
        If InStr(currentUrl, "http") > 0 Then    'test
            'call the sub and extract value
            output(i) = MM_description(currentUrl, i, ie)
        End If
    Next i
    ie.Quit
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("F1").Resize(UBound(output), 1) = Application.Transpose(output)
End Sub

Public Function MM_description(ByVal currentUrl As String, ByVal i As Long, ByVal ie As Object) As String

    Dim codeLine As String, startPos As Long, endPos As Long, mes As String

    With ie
        .Navigate2 currentUrl

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        mes = .document.body.innerHTML
        startPos = InStr(mes, "Description") + 61
        endPos = InStr(mes, "Address")

        If startPos = 0 Then
            MM_description = "Not Found"
        Else
            codeLine = Mid$(mes, startPos, endPos - startPos - 229)
            MM_description = codeLine
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you give two examples of the contents of table6? .. By the way, endPost As Long should be endPos As Long

Comment: We need the OP to provide this. In my case I set up a test table called Table6 in Sheet1 and in column 1 of that table I have urls.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Sorry.... just seen your last comment.... many thanks and well spotted!

Comment: Wauv, this was amazing @QHarr!

"Table6": is a single column range, and it contains the urls. One url in each cell which goes from BL7:BL356

Regarding the "if empty" command. Some of the cells are empty, but I need the loop to simply continue,  because after a blank cell there will be cells contianing urls.

And @YasserKhalil, thank you for noting the endPost. I found out when using Option explicit

Comment: Then the re-write at the end should work. It is based on Table6 being an actual excel table i.e. ListObject. Is your table an actual Excel table?

Comment: No, it is just a named range

Comment: Make it a table and call it Table6 is simplest fix.